# LINQ: Get min and max values of sequence of numbers divided into subsequences

Tags: linq

how can I split a sequence of numbers into subgroups of numbers and get the local minimum and maximum of the subgroups with linq?

If I have a sequence of, lets say 11 items { 3, 2, 5, 9, 9, 6, 7, 2, 5, 11, 2 }
I want to split this into subgroups with 3 or less items.

So I get the following 4 subgroups: { 3, 2, 5 } , { 9, 9, 6 } , { 7, 2, 5}  , { 11, 2}

The final return values of the LinQ expression (getting min and max for each group) should be 2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 7, 2, 11

TIA,
Sascha

Comment: You have `6` in two groups, and dropped the `5`. What if you have a group of one number? `{1,2,3}{4}`?

Comment: @Kobi: It was likely a typo, though it didn't affect what the desired result would be (as far as I can tell).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it.

```
var numbers = new[] { 3, 2, 5, 9, 9, 6, 7, 2, 5, 11, 2 };
var query = from p in numbers.Select((n, i) => new { n, Group = i / 3 })
            group p.n by p.Group into g
            from n in new[] { g.Min(), g.Max() }
            select n;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, using [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)'s [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) method to do the grouping, you could use:

```
var query = source.Batch(3, batch => new[] { batch.Min(), batch.Max() })
                  .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: One point is that the last item will be doubled if it is alone in its group. `{1}`->`{1,1}`.  Of course, it fits the requirements.